# Loaded content via jQuery is not visible in the Mac/Safari Browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

My page "inicio.html" currently contains this script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#my_site_content").load("inicio.html");
});
```

and in a body of that page:

```
<div id="my_site_content"> </div>
```

I have tested this in Chrome/IE7/IE8/Firefox and it works fine, however, on Safari, the page inicio.html doesn't work at all. I also have a Nivo Slider on the page and cufon tags for the font, though it doesn't work in Safari. What's going on?

OBS: If I only open inicio.html, the page works perfect, but not when I load this inside a div in another page.

EDIT: [PAGE LINK](http://www.alsite.com.br/melaniboto/)

Comment: Loading a wcomplete HTML document (including the outer `<html>` tag etc) into the middle of *another* page is going to give you potentially bizarre results because the resulting DOM doesn't make any sense.

Comment: will be hard to debug if we have no access to that page or can see it's source.  What's it's content?

Comment: It works for me in safari 4.1 and firefox 3.6 on osx 10.5.8

Comment: i have safari 5.0.2 and dont work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to realize, whether that function will run. If no, you've got anser. Second, you need to see this div, so add border or background color. then try to run that function, maybe it will just disapper. don't forget to set width and height. last, check, if there is any problem with  element, because if inicio.html have html, body and so on elements, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: I think the problem lies with inicio.html not with all the rest otherwise it wouldn't load in other browsers would it?